# creating rewrite rule in .htacess in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess rewrite rule that works properly:

```
RewriteRule ^property/([0-9]+)/?$ /property/?prop=$1 [L]
```

I am trying to change this rule to allow alphanumeric and dashes but as soon as I change that bit I get a 500 internal server error. assuming it might be a conflict with the wordpress rules?

```
http://sample.com/property/test-here
```

should go to

```
http://sample.com/property/?prop=test-here
```

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: I don't believe I have access to an error log.. just an access log

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong with the rule that would cause a 500 error. I assume you have mod_rewrite enabled? Note: the regex in the rule only includes numbers and your example has letters and a dash.